# Create a shared Microfrontend containing css and fonts that to be shared across other microfrontend?

Tags: reactjs, webpack-module-federation

I have a fonts.css and styles.css created a separate mfe like below
[image]

I want to use the shared mfe code in other mfe during deployment and production using module federation